# how can I call multiple category by ID in a model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Model::::

```
public function selectCategory($per_page, $offset)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $this->db->where('category_id', 23);
    //$this->db->order_by("category_id", "desc"); 

    $query = $this->db->get('', $per_page, $offset);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        $data[] = $row;

    return $data;
}
```

This model is working well. Now I want to call multiple id from my db table such as :::

```
 $this->db->where('category_id', 23 && 24);
```

In this case it is showing error... "Message: Undefined variable: data" ... Help me to get multiple ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to get items that correspond to either of two categories, then you need an OR statement:

```
WHERE category_id = 23 OR category_id = 24,
```

Using CI's Active Record class:

```
$this->db->where('category_id', 23);
$this->db->or_where('category_id', 24);
```

**UPDATE**

Your error "Undefined variable: data" is because your query is not producing any results so $data is never declared, add $data = array(); before your loop:

```
$query = $this->db->get('', $per_page, $offset);
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    $data[] = $row;

return $data;
```

Comment: $this->db->where('category_id', 23);
$this->db->where('category_id', 24);  ......................  is getting error ::"Message: Undefined variable: data"

Comment: you need to declare $data outside the foreach loop because your query is not getting any results

Comment: My Controller ::::...................                                                 $data['result']=$this->accessories_model->selectCategory($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('accessories_view',$data,TRUE);
$this->load->view('home', $data);

Comment: just add `$data = array()` before your foreach loop

Comment: this is not showing any error and data :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  $query = $this->db->get('', $per_page, $offset);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            $data[] = $row;

        return $data;

Comment: yes because you probably don't have any items in your table with both ids (23 & 24) do you mean to use OR instead of AND?

Comment: I have some data on that table ::: when I call 23 then it shows the data. But I want to show data from 23 and 24 ids. It is not working... please help me

Comment: just chill out a bit, you want rows that have id 23 and rows that have id 24? if so then you need OR instead of AND, see the update in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much that I have got the solutions from your instruction that ::::: It is working perfectly :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: $this->db->where('category_id', 23);
        $this->db->or_where('category_id', 24);

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted things out, don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as "accepted" by clicking on the green check mark next to it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

you should try this it will select where id=23 or 24

```
$this->db->where('category_id', 23);
$this->db->or_where('category_id', 24);
```

you can also use

```
$ids= array('23', '24');
$this->db->where_in('category_id', $ids);
```

Comment: It is working perfectly ::::: thanks a lot :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: $this->db->where('category_id', 22);
$this->db->or_where('category_id', 23);